# Mocking a suspend function asks for an extra parameter - Mockito

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a suspend function which accepts 3 parameters, but when I try to mock it asks for 4 parameters

```
  suspend fun notifyBandSuspend(serviceType: String, id: String, action: TimeAction): GenericResponse =
        order.serviceOrderband(serviceType, id, action)
```

Mocking

```
when(repository.notifyBandSuspend(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new GenericResponse());
```

Error is - Expected 4 arguments but found 3

Imports

```
  // Mockito
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.0"
```

Any idea how to fix this please

EDIT

as it was complaining about 4th parameter
I passed 4 parameters like this

```
when(orderRepository.notifyBandSuspend(anyString(), anyString(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new GenericResponse());
```

that gives me an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 4 recorded:
```

Error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 4 recorded:
-> at com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.ServiceOrderViewScenario.setup(ServiceOrderViewScenario.java:46)
-> at com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.ServiceOrderViewScenario.setup(ServiceOrderViewScenario.java:46)
-> at com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.ServiceOrderViewScenario.setup(ServiceOrderViewScenario.java:46)
-> at com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.ServiceOrderViewScenario.setup(ServiceOrderViewScenario.java:46)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

at com.xxx.xx.clean.orderview.data.OrderRepository.notifyBandSuspend(OrderRepository.kt:22)
at com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.ServiceOrderViewScenario.setup(ServiceOrderViewScenario.java:46)
at com.xxx.xx.test.BaseTest.scenario(BaseTest.java:79)
at com.xxx.xx.test.ServiceOrderViewTests.testAirStartOrder(ServiceOrderViewTests.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at com.xxx.xx.test.runner.UnlockDeviceAndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(UnlockDeviceAndroidJUnitRunner.java:42)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

Thanks
Rao

Comment: Maybe you have an overload of the method that uses 4 parameters and that's the one the mock object is calling

Comment: Yes, the suspend function expects last argument to be a [Continuation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-continuation/), from point of view from JVM. While if you call it inside from a coroutine, it is implicitly passed.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i then passed the 4th parameter which gave me an error. I updated the question

Comment: Try with this `when(orderRepository.notifyBandSuspend(anyString(), anyString(), any(TimeAction.class))).thenReturn(new GenericResponse());`

Comment: @DCruz22 i tried that but with same error `expected 4 arguments`

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace for that error?

Comment: @DCruz22 i have added it to the question

Comment: @BRDroid both errors you posted say `3 matchers expected, 4 recorded`

Comment: yes that is when I passes 4 as it asked for it

Comment: did you try using mockito-kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a `null` instead of a `Continuation` parameter (worked for me on Mockito 4.5.1)